# How do you work with dev, pre and prod with Snowpack?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, package.json, snowpack

I want to define environment variables in my `package.json` where I'm using Snowpack, but as far as I know Snowpack sets the `NODE_ENV` automatically based on [dev vs build](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/environment-variables).

Is it possible to define variables for 3 modes instead of 2, I mean:

- development
- preproduction
- production

These are my scripts in my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "snowpack dev",
    "build": "snowpack build NODE_ENV=pre",
    "build:production": "snowpack build NODE_ENV=pro"
}
```

However,  `import.meta.env.MODE` returns `production` for the 2 types of build.

I couldn't make it work, maybe there is another way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

My use case was not exactly the same, but similar, and you should be able to generate as many different environments as you want with this technique.

I was able to do this by writing a custom snowpack plugin to use `.env` files with the `dotenv` npm package, and two separate `snowpack.config.js` files; one for dev and one for prod. Here's how...

1. Add `dotenv` to your project: `npm i -D dotenv`
2. Create this new file. This will be our custom snowpack plugin

```js
// env-loader.js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
module.exports = function plugin(snowpackConfig, { path }) {
  dotenv.config({ path: path });
  return { name: 'Custom plugin from StackOverflow' };
};
```

3. Create your .env files; `.env.develop` and `.env.production`
4. Create your snowpack.config files; `snowpack-develop.config.js` and `snowpack-production.config.js`
5. Add your custom plugin to both snowpack.config files. Be sure to give it the correct path to your custom plugin, and the correct path to your .env files.

```js
// snowpack-develop.config.js
const path = require('path'); 
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ['./path/to/env-loader', { path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.develop.env') }],
  ],
};
```

6. Finally, add your npm scripts. Point your dev scripts to the snowpack-develop file, and prod to the snowpack-production file.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "snowpack dev --config ./snowpack-develop.config.js",
    "build:dev": "snowpack build --config ./snowpack-develop.config.js",
    "build:prod": "snowpack build --config ./snowpack-production.config.js"
  },
```

In snowpack, environment variables must include the prefix `SNOWPACK_PUBLIC_`, and to use a variable in your code you would access it like this: `import.meta.env.SNOWPACK_PUBLIC_MY_VARIABLE`. It runs a find-and-replace at build time.

[Snowpack Config Docs](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration)
[Snowpack Plugin Docs](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/plugins)
[Snowpack Env Docs](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/environment-variables)